# How do I make a screenreader automatically read cell contents?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I'm trying to use a CSS table to represent a grid of items. My screenreader (NVDA) will automatically read the contents of a focusable div, but not if the div is `display: table-cell`. Is there a way to make the contents be automatically be read upon tabbing?

```html
<div style="display: block" tabindex="0">Apple (for comparison)</div><br>
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell" tabindex="0">Banana</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell" tabindex="0">Celery</div>
        <!-- Screenreader won't say banana or celery upon tabbing -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an [aria grid (or table) role](http://rawgit.com/w3c/aria/master/aria/aria.html#grid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it (thanks @bishop). I used `role="grid"`, `role="row"` and `role="gridcell"` to make it a grid then used `aria-readonly="true"` to indicate that the grid is not editable.

```html
<div style="display: block" tabindex="0">Apple (for comparison)</div><br>
<div role="grid" aria-readonly="true" style="display: table">
    <div role="row" style="display: table-row">
        <div role="gridcell" style="display: table-cell" tabindex="0">Banana</div>
        <div role="gridcell" style="display: table-cell" tabindex="0">Celery</div>
    </div>
</div>
```